Error 404 not found on all routes Node TypeScript Azure Function App
I I am getting an error 404 Not Found  on all routes on request to mine api. I can't figure out how to write the code correctly. Here example of my code:
host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        }
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
    }
}

local.settings.json:
 "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
      "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
    }

index.ts:
import { app } from "@azure/functions";


app.http("hello", {
  methods: ["GET"],
  authLevel: "anonymous",
  route: "hello",
  handler: helloController.hello.bind(helloController),
});


helloController:
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

class HelloController {
  public async hello(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      return res.sendStatus(200).json("Hello World");
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  }
}

export const helloController = new HelloController();

.yml:
name: Build and deploy Node.js project to Azure Function App - buxonline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - node_version
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: 'backend' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  NODE_VERSION: '20.x' # set this to the node version to use (supports 8.x, 10.x, 12.x)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Node ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }} Environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}

      - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Npm'
        shell: bash
        run: |
          pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
          popd

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_689801BD1C5E47F3B0BE98C1A283FD1E }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_5D60349DAA2042FEB1925BC25A5A1309 }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_DB7120F777A048AFAF9B033F5A591B7A }}

      - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: fa
        with:
          app-name: 'buxonline'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}


Structure of my project:
-project-root:

.github

workflows

nameofmyyml.yml




backend

.env

.eslintrc.js

host.json

local.settings.json

package.json

tsconfig.json

src

config

constants

controllers

enum

error

middleware

models

routers

services

statics

types

app.ts,

index.ts





dist


I Wrote  like usual async function, write like azure function. Tried some methods in handler but nothing changed

Is this code working locally?

Yes its working locally

Please share your GitHub repository link if possible.

https://github.com/vmakar9/proj-buxonlinenode

Are you getting any errors during deployment?

During deployment no. After that in Azure portal shows Functions that are not triggering No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

And The SMB share will be mounted on /home/ directory. It will be shared across scale instances and files written will persist across restarts. If this is not the expected behavior for your custom container, please configure WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE to false in app settings.

Did you try deploying to Azure App Service?

I'm already deployed on Azure Function App but i cant reach to routers every time i had 404 not found

Run the project locally: you should be able to see the function trigger in console locally, else it won't sync the trigger after deploying to Azure Function App.

Create a new controller to return the response as mentioned in the similar project found in @Github.

Sample Code:

HomeController:

import { BaseController } from './BaseController.js'
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit } from '@azure/functions'

export class HelloController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Handle the incoming request
     * @param request
     */
    public async index(request: HttpRequest): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
        const name = request.query.get('name')

        return {
            status: 200,
            jsonBody: {
                message: name ? `Hello, ${name}!` : 'Hello World!'
            }
        }
    }

}


BaseController:

write the code to return the Http response.
import type { HttpResponseInit } from '@azure/functions'

export abstract class BaseController {
    protected abort(code: number, message: string = ''): HttpResponseInit {
        return {
            status: code,
            body: message
        }
    }
}

Folder Structure:
|---.vscode
|---node_modules
|---.deployment
|---.eslintrc.js
|---.funcignore
|---.gitignore
|---host.json
|---local.settings.json
|---package.json
|---package-lock.json
|---tsconfig.json
\---src
    +---app
    |   \---Http
    |       \---Controllers
    |               BaseController.ts
    |               HelloController.ts
    |
    +---bootstrap
    |       app.ts
    |
    +---routes
    |       api.ts
    |
    \---services
        +---Cache
        |       CacheManager.ts
        |       contracts.ts
        |       exceptions.ts
        |       MemoryStore.ts
        |       Repository.ts
        |
        +---Container
        |       Container.ts
        |       contracts.ts
        |       exceptions.ts
        |       types.d.ts
        |
        \---Route
                contracts.ts
                Route.ts


Run the function locally:


Portal:

Deployed to Azure functions:


